# Is it true that if you are pregnant you should not walk bare foot?

Tags: pregnancy

My mother and my grandma told me when I was pregnant I should never walk barefoot because I would get sick as you absorb everything from your feet.

Is this an old wives' tale ?

Comment: Similar claim, but in [Mongolia](http://saltygrace426.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/dating.html) "I was also told that if I didn't wear socks and slippers then my feet would get cold (obviously) and that I would have womb problems later in life (?)."

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the suggestion, but that seems to be a different claim - that non-pregnant woman should not let their feet get cold feet to remain fertile.

Comment: There are certainly risks from walking barefoot (injuries, hookworm), but I haven't found claims related to pregnancy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot_and_pregnant